# Angular2 promise - returning functions that already return a promise

Tags: angular

I've written the following function - I'm trying to return existing promise functions without needed to wrap them in a custom promise:

```
doAuthWithPrompt(): Promise <any> {
      this.getUser() // returns promise
      .then (user => {
        if (user == undefined) {
          this.promptForPassword() // returns promise
          .then (data => {
            return this.doAuth(data.email, data.password); // returns promise
          })
        }
        else {
            return this.doAuth(user.email, user.password) // returns promise
          };

      })
      .catch (e => {return Promise.reject(false);}) 

  }
```

The error I am getting in my IDE (Visual Studio Code) is:

> [ts] A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must
>   return a value.

What am I missing while defining `doAuthWithPrompt`? thanks.

Comment: You need to `return this.getUser().then..`

Comment: Thanks! why don't I also need to `return this.promptForPassword()` ?

Comment: @echonax why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @user1361529 oh I didn't see the chained promises, you should do that too.

Comment: @0mpurdy sorry, I felt a bit lazy I guess :-) (and to avoid follow-up questions :P)

Comment: @echonax , I'm incorrigible. I followed up on your comments - sorry :p

Comment: @user1361529 haha, I'll provide it as an answer.

Comment: @echonax do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the wrapper `Promise` and its chained promises also:

```
doAuthWithPrompt(): Promise <any> {
      return this.getUser() // returns promise
        .then (user => {
           if (user == undefined) {
             return this.promptForPassword() // returns promise
               .then (data => {
                 return this.doAuth(data.email, data.password); // returns promise
               })
           } else {
             return this.doAuth(user.email, user.password) // returns promise
           }    
      })
      .catch (e => {return Promise.reject(false);})     
}
```